# WIX Deployment: Which files to deploy?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wix

This might be a very trivial question but deployment is new to me and little confused about which file to deploy.

I have a WPF test project uses Entity framework in visual studio and trying to use WIX to deploy it. Target machine is running windows 7. Given that .Net Framework and sql server localdb is installed on the target machine what files I need to deploy (make component in the WIX xml file)? I have tried copying the whole bin/Release folder to the target machine and it works. However I don’t know if that is necessary. The following screenshot shows the bin\Release directory of my application.

[image]

The problem is I don’t know the job of some files particularly the files with the following extensions:

1. .exe.config
2. .pdb
3. .vshost.exe
4. .vshost.exe.config

The database file is located in the Users\[username] directory and gets created if it doesn’t exist so I suppose it’s not part of the deployment. 
Additionally I would like to understand two xml files-

1. EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml
2. EntityFramework.xml

Do I need to deploy these two files as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exe.config
```

Several settings you can change here - if defined in the Project building the EXE. You probably want to deploy this.

```
.pdb
```

Debugfiles. Deploy if you are investigating errors - else don't, these contain source information.

```
.vshost.exe
.vshost.exe.config
```

Do not deploy. These are used/generate by Visual Studio. If you start a Project out of Visual Studio it is ran in a hosted process environment so it cannot crash Visual Studio when then application runs into an error. Not for production.

```
EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml
EntityFramework.xml
```

This is documentation for the corresponding dlls. Useful for development, I do not think you want to deploy them thou.